# Группировка по timeseries в диапазоне

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня сейчас есть таблица такого типа:

```
create_time; ts_1; ts_2
'2021-03-12'; [1615562361, 1615562691, 1615563290]; [1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562361, 1615562579, 1615562614, 1615562619, 1615562619, 1615562640, 1615562645, 1615563483, 1615563649, 1615563668, 1615563683, 1615563756, 1615573629, 1615573651, 1615573668, 1615576345, 1615576348, 1615633987, 1615636283]
[1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562284, 1615562361, 1615562579, 1615562614, 1615562619, 1615562619, 1615562640, 1615562645, 1615563483, 1615563649, 1615563668, 1615563683, 1615563756, 1615573629, 1615573651, 1615573668, 1615576345, 1615576348, 1615633987, 1615636283]
...   
'2021-04-25'; [1619334357, 1619334511]; [1619332800, 1619332800, 1619332800, 1619332837, 1619332857, 1619333043, 1619333130, 1619333150, 1619333163, 1619333168, 1619333174, 1619333176, 1619333176, 1619333249, 1619333441, 1619333448, 1619333488, 1619333497, 1619333703, 1619333772, 1619333790, 1619333879, 1619333893, 1619333920, 1619333934, 1619334131, 1619334152, 1619334357, 1619334365, 1619334395, 1619334410, 1619334555, 1619335949, 1619336366, 1619336665, 1619336951, 1619337155, 1619337717, 1619337745, 1619337779, 1619337788, 1619351471, 1619351482, 1619355713, 1619355743, 1619355789, 1619431125, 1619431147, 1619431168, 1619431171, 1619431193, 1619431196, 1619431205, 1619431211, 1619431214, 1619431230, 1619431232, 1619431249, 1619763084, 1619763101, 1619763104, 1619763212, 1619763213, 1619763300, 1619763383]
```

Задача у меня такого плана, взять дату create_time и в диапазоне от create_time до create_time + 30 дней. Посчитать для каждого дня сколько (т.е. для 2021-03-12, 2021-03-13, ..., 2021-04-11) событий произошло типа ts_1 и ts_2.

В итоге я хочу получить таблицу вида:

```
create_time; ts_1; ts_2
'2021-03-12', [5, 4, 0, 0, ... 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0]
'2021-04-25', [3, 2, 0, 0, ... 1, 0], [0, 3, 1, ..., 0, 0]
```

Где каждый массив `ts_1, ts_2` имеет 30 значений. Числа в массивах условные, я не считал для данных выше верные значения.

Есть лишь неоптимальная идея, поэтому рад любым идеям как это сделать оптимально.